# Prove $\left(1-\epsilon\right)^x\leqslant\left(1-\epsilon x\right)$ and $\left(1+\epsilon\right)^x\leqslant\left(1+\epsilon x\right)$

Tags: real-analysis

Prove the following inequalities with at least two methods: $\forall\, x\in[0, 1]$ and  $\epsilon\in[0, \dfrac{1}{2}]$:

$$
\left(1-\epsilon\right)^x\leqslant\left(1-\epsilon x\right).
$$

$$
\left(1+\epsilon\right)^x\leqslant\left(1+\epsilon x\right).
$$

I would like to get any idea of how to do it (of course you do not need to give me two methods). Any suggestions will be appreciated.

How I did the first one: I proved that $\left(1-\epsilon\right)^x$ is a convex function of $x$.
How I did the second: I showed also that $\left(1+\epsilon\right)^x$ is a convex function of $x$. So I think I am done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see the 'generalization' section in here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality

Comment: Oh, thank you very much. I did not know that.